# How can I find the limit of the $s_n=n[1+(-1)^n]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> $s_n=n[1+(-1)^n]$

Any hints on how to get started with this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$s_{2n} = 4n \to \infty, s_{2n+1} = 0 \to 0$. Thus the subsequences go to different limits, hence the limit does not exist.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on how you came up with those subsequences a little?

Comment: When you get alternating sequences: $(-1)^n$, it's really natural to look at the "even terms" and "odd terms" subsequences.

Comment: @free_mind: the sequence looks like $0,4,0,8,0,12,\ldots $ so it is fairly obvious

Comment: (-1)^n is -1 if n is odd.  (-1)^n =1 if n is even.  That is something that should be basic.  With experience, (-1)^n should become the imediately and obvious basis to express "one value for even terms another for odd terms".  So (1+(-1)^n) is 0 if n is odd and 2 if n is odd.  So s (n) = 2n if n is even and 0 if n is odd.